# FIRApp must be imported

Tags: ios, build, expo, react-native-firebase

(node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/ios/RNFBFirestore/RNFBFirestoreTransactionModule.m:85:77)

83 |       [RNFBFirestoreCommon promiseRejectFirestoreException:reject error:error];
84 |     } else {

> 85 |       NSString *appName = [RNFBSharedUtils getAppJavaScriptName:firebaseApp.name];
> |                                                                             ^ definition of 'FIRApp' must be imported from module 'RNFBApp.RCTConvert_FIRApp' before it is required`

Getting this error while running expo run:ios, I included the Firebase in the AppDelegate.mm at the top , also modified Podfile according to the Fb documentation. Any help will be appreciated , did anyone else have this issue ? Thanks.

react-native-firebase 18.5.0
FirebaseSDK 10.15.0
expo 6.3.1
expo sdk 49.0.16
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.72.6
cocoapods : 1.13.0